# How to use VAR model for model forecasting

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering, forecasting, inference, vector-autoregression

Good evening, everyone.
I am a software engineer and I am studying the VAR model and its advantages and disadvantages. Specifically, my question is the following: is it possible to use VAR to predict the cost of a variable (e.g., the cost of a service) based on some predictors, such as income, customer age, and location (example), with the goal of segmenting customers to identify clusters with similar characteristics and create targeted promotions.

It is my understanding that VAR is used for this and to understand whether and how the variables intercut to achieve the predictive goal of a measure.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you envisage the use of VAR in such a context? For the part preceding clustering, multiple linear regression rather than a VAR seems a more natural tool for the job.

Comment: @RichardHardy Actually, for this problem I used XGBoost for my simulation on synthetic data. 
However, I also wanted to use a statistical method that also allows me to perform confidence levels on the prediction to understand a range of plausible values in which the true value of the variable is believed to lie with some probability. 
In particular, I would like to understand how my variables affect each other and particularly whether and how past values affect future values.
Definitely, I would perform further analysis with multiple regression.

Comment: @RichardHardy VAR allows me to perform proper statistical analysis for a feature selection plus prediction of variable Y on future data, no?

Comment: The A in VAR stands for *auto*. Are you going to predict multiple variables based on their own histories and the histories of the other variables? Because that is what VAR does.

Comment: @RichardHardy
Yes I know.

My goal is to predict one or more dependent variables (Y) based on two or more independent variables (X).

For example, predict the cost of a service and a subscription in the year 2024 based on the past values ​​of Y and X (years 2021, 2022, 2023) and understand if these independent variables (X) are useful in contributing to the forecast of the variables Y or not, making a real feature selection.

Comment: Well, then I guess that answers your question?

Comment: @RichardHardy , I suppose that the answer is positive: I can use VAR for this purpose of mine (and ARIMA & SARIMA models too), right?

Comment: It seems so, though I do not fully understand your problem setting.

Comment: @RichardHardy

I'll try to explain myself better: I have a set of independent variables (or predictors) X, and one or more output variables Y (for example the cost of a service).
I want to make a prediction about the next year of Y based on the past values ​​of Y and X (for example in the years 2021 and 2022 and 2023).

Clearly, I'm not sure if these X's are "useful" in helping me predict the value of Y (for example, I think income affects the cost of a service, but it may be that from real data this dependence doesn't exist and I would therefore discard income as a predictor).

Comment: Yes, a VAR should work for such a task.

Comment: @RichardHardy Ok, thank you! I think that also ARIMA & SARIMA should work for this task!

Answer (score 0):

A VAR model can be used to predict multiple variables based on their own histories and the histories of the other variables. Based on your clarifying comments, it seems you are interested in doing that, so indeed you could use a VAR model.

Regarding the use of ARIMA and SARIMA, they would not allow including any explanatory variables besides the dependent variable. This way they do not fit your purpose. But you could add some external regressors and run regression with (S)ARIMA errors (such as implemented by `stats::arima`, `forecast::Arima` and `forecast::auto.arima` in R) or a (S)ARIMAX model.

(This is for the part of analysis that precedes segmentation/clustering.)

Comment: Good morning, thank you very much for the explanation. 
So, regarding ARIMA & S(ARIMA) I could just predict the cost of the dependent variable based on the values of the latter and it would still be a second result since I did the same with XGBoost. 
My project is developed in Python.

Comment: @AlessandroPioBudetti, I am a little confused by your phrasing, but here is what I think. You can use VAR and (S)ARIMA for the task and you can use XGBoost, too, if you like. It does not matter whether you do it in Python, R or some other program/language.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I am using the translator. Anyway it's okay thank you very much, now I'm trying to do it with ARIMA, and then do it with SARIMA and with VAR when I add more dependent variables.